# Jquery slidedown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-slider

I'm pretty much new to the jquery library, so I was experimenting with some jquery functions. This is the code I wrote

```
<html>
<head>
<title>slide</title>

    <style>
        .outer  {

            width: 700px;
            height: 1000px;
            border: 2px dashed green;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        .box    {
            widht: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 2px solid green;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' id='btn' value='click' />
    <div class='outer'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
        $('#btn').click(function()  {
            $('.outer').prepend("<div class='box'></div>");
            $('.box').slideDown(3000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

As you see, if i click the button, a new div prepends to the parent div. However the jquery slideDown function doesn't seem to have any effect but when I used slideUp, it worked as expected. So whenever i click the button the new div is created but no slidedown animation takes place. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

`box` cannot slide down, because the `box` is already being displayed.

Set `display:none` on your `.box` css rule, and you should get the effect you are after.

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UDj5y/

---

If you don't wish to make changes to your CSS, you can use the following jQuery code instead:

```
$box = $("<div class='box'></div>");
$('.outer').prepend($box);
$box.hide().slideDown(3000);
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UDj5y/1/

```js
$('#btn').click(function()  {
    $box = $("<div class='box'></div>");
    $('.outer').prepend($box);
    $box.hide().slideDown(3000);
});
```

```css
.outer  {

    width: 700px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 2px dashed green;
    margin: 20px;
}

.box    {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' id='btn' value='click' />
<div class='outer'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you prepend the div it is automatically shown, so `slideDown` has nothing to do.

You have 2 options:

```
.box    {
            widht: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 2px solid green;
            margin: 20px;
            display: none;
        }
```

or in jquery:

```
$('.box').hide().slideDown(3000);
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GPhcc/

Comment: Not so keen on this solution. This is hiding all boxes, and making them all slideDown each time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rv2ap/

The reason it wasn't working is your box was visible when it was appended. This means the animation could not be run.

All you need to do is add `display: none;` to your css rules for `.box`

Answer (score 1):

You should hide it:

```
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

If you don't do it, then box will appear immediately.